# PostgreSQL default cluster?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I didn't remember creating a cluster but directly went to create database.

Using `pg_lsclusters`, I found that I have a cluster as following with my db

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner      Data directory               
9.3 main    5432 online postgres   /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
```

I was reading the PostgreSQL documentation but couldn't find relevant info.

I have the following questions:

1. Does PostgreSQL automatically create default cluster? And if so, is it good practice to use it?
2. Does PostgreSQL also automatically start the default cluster? I never started but its status is online and I can see it in system-monitor.

Thanks for any clarifications!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really asking about "PostgreSQL on Debian or Ubuntu", as it's the packaging and wrapper utilities doing this, not PostgreSQL its self.

See [the PostgreSQL help on the Ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL) for information. This mostly applies to Debian too, since it uses the same style of packaging for PostgreSQL.

To your specific questions:

> Does PostgreSQL automatically create default cluster? And if so, is it good practice to use it?

Strictly `pg_wrapper`, the Ubuntu/Debian tool that manages PostgreSQL installs, creates it. Yes, it's fine to use it and there's generally not much reason not to.

> Does PostgreSQL also automatically start the default cluster?

This depends on your operating system and its PostgreSQL packages, not on PostgreSQL its self. For information on how to configure what starts on Ubuntu, see [Boot Howto - Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBootupHowto).

Comment: is there any way to skip the creation of the default cluster when installing postgresql on Ubuntu (or Debian)?

Comment: @Reinsbrain Don't know off the top of my head; post a new question. Also check the packaging post-install script